# jasmine-jquery fixtures not loading

Tags: fixtures, jasmine-jquery

Problem is that **jasmine-jquery** in not loading my fixtures from **spec/fixtures** folder. Now when I look at jasmine-jquery source code default path for fixtures is **spec/javascripts/fixtures**. 
In a version that I have, there is no **spec/javascripts/fixtures** folder. It seems it is something for Ruby gem. I also tried to create that **javascripts folder** but still it can't load it. When I place my fixture fragment inside of SpecRunner.html body - it works.

Here is my html fragment:

```
<ul class="fr">
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Spec file:

```
describe("something to describe", function() {

    it("should see a DOM element", function() {
        loadFixtures("custom.html");
        expect($(".fr")).toExist();
    });
});
```

Is that a bug or something with the path ?

**Solved:
It is a problem with google-chrome. By default it doesn't allow access to other domain by same origin policy. Solution is to run app from local server, or to use firefox.**

Answer (score 4):

It indeed has to do with Chrome. This is a security concept called [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Instead of running Firefox or the app from local server, you can still use Chrome with that security check disabled.

Just run Chrome/Chromium with the command-line argument `--allow-file-access-from-files`:

```
google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

**Remember!** Since this is a security feature, by disabling it you are putting your computer at risk. It is recommended to only use this parameter when testing local websites/apps (via a different shortcut/alias).