# Jasmine-jQuery loadFixtures is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm still new to the whole jasmine things and in past few hours I stuck in this problem. 
I tried to load an external fixture file using loadFixture().
I use Jasmine 2.0.0 and Jasmine-jQuery 2.0.5.

```
ReferenceError: loadFixtures is not defined
  at Suite.<anonymous> (--appname--/app/assets/Tester/spec/ChannelSpec.js:5:6)
  at Env.describe (--appname--/app/assets/Tester/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js:613:25)
  at jasmineInterface.describe (--appname--/app/assets/Tester/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js:37:18)
  at Suite.<anonymous>  (--appname--/app/assets/Tester/spec/ChannelSpec.js:2:3)
  at Env.describe (--appname--/app/assets/Tester/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js:613:25)
  at jasmineInterface.describe (--appname--/app/assets/Tester/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js:37:18)
  at --appname--/app/assets/Tester/spec/ChannelSpec.js:1:1
```

while in Chromium console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'spiedEventsKey' of undefined
```

this is the line in ChannelSpec.js

```
1. describe('Channel', function() {
2.  describe('Test Restriction', function() {
3.     var $httpBackend,service;
4.     // jasmine.getFixtures().proxyCallTo_('load', 'fixtures.html')
5.     loadFixtures('fixtures.html');
```

I work on Ubuntu 14.04 and primarily use Chromium but I tried on Firefox as some people suggested that it's [Same-Origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18434001/3797539), but it produced similar error.

**---Solved---**

It's solved by loading jasmine-jquery last

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you see that jasmine-jquery.js is loading properly if you look in firebug/developer tools?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Using Firefox, in console i can click on the link to jasmine-jquery.js (left of the error definition) with no problem. It also shows on "Debugger -> Source". I've also redownloaded it twice in case of corrupted file.

Comment: Are you loading all of the relevant jasmine libs before jasmine-jquery?  I am loading jasmine.js, jasmine-html.js and boot.js first.

Comment: Derp, that solved it! I didn't know that script order is very important in JS. Thanks Nick !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you are loading Jasmine before you load the Jasmine-jQuery library.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and if you use require.js you should set up dependencies in shim configuration:

```
requirejs.s.contexts._.config.shim["jasmine-jquery"] = {
   deps: ['jasmine', 'jquery'], 
   exports: 'jasmine-jquery'
}
```

just for example, if you start your tests on the same port and use the same require.js config, as in main application ("requirejs.s.contexts._.config" is a quick way to patch require config in jasmine runner)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when installing package with bower, but not initing bower_components directory first.

In this case, run:

```
bower init
```

and then re-install

```
bower install jasmine-jquery --save
```